# Read certain folders based on a variable

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

I have below folder structure:

```
/mnt/tmp/fldr1
/mnt/tmp/fldr2
/mnt/tmp/fldr3
/mnt/tmp/fldr4
/mnt/tmp/fldr5
/mnt/tmp/fldr6
```

Based on a variable I would be reading the parquet files from certain folders.

```
eg. 
if trail = 2 I would read only fldr1 and fldr2
if trail = 4 I would read only fldr1, fldr2, fldr3 and fldr4
if trail = 6 I would read all the folders
```

I have the below code.

```
scala> val cnt = 2
val cnt: Int = 2

scala> val xs = List(1, cnt)
val xs: List[Int] = List(1, 2)

scala> val ys = List("/mnt/tmp1", "/mnt/tmp2")
val ys: List[String] = List(/mnt/tmp1, /mnt/tmp2)

scala> val cross = xs.flatMap(x => ys.map(y => (y + "/trial=" + x.toString)))
val cross: List[String] = List(/mnt/tmp1/trial=1, /mnt/tmp2/trial=1, /mnt/tmp1/trial=2, /mnt/tmp2/trial=2)
```

I would then read through the paths and get the parquet files.

Is there any other easier way to do this?

Comment: do you just need a skeleton - how to read from a dir based on the variable, or you want a complete program for spark?

Comment: I have edited the question with the code I just wrote...not sure if there is any better way to do this!

Answer (score 0):

a basic skeleton can be:

```scala
val dirsstr="/mnt/tmp/fldr1,/mnt/tmp/fldr2,/mnt/tmp/fldr3,/mnt/tmp/fldr4,/mnt/tmp/fldr5,/mnt/tmp/fldr6"
val dirs = dirsstr.split(",")

//get an random generator - you will have your own input
val trail = scala.util.Random

trail.nextInt(6) match{
  case 2 => {
    readFiles(dirs(0));
    readFiles(dirs(1));
  }
  case 4 => for(i <- (0 to 3)) readFiles(dirs(i));
  case 6 => dirs.foreach(dir => readFiles(dir))
  case _ => println("Out of scope of your question :)")
}
```

where `readFiles` depends on your spark, parquet context. Sure, there can be many other (maybe better) ways how to do it,